# Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, как правильнее

Tags: согласование

Есть сомнения касательно структуры предложения:

Вариант 1:
Если понять только то, что написано в Писании, то естественным образом обретается вера и понимание всех последующих комментариев.

Вариант 2 (добавлена «в» после «вера»):
Если понять только то, что написано в Писании, то естественным образом обретается вера **в** и понимание всех последующих комментариев.

Кажется, что в первом варианте нет должного согласования. Но я не помню, можно ли писать так, как описано во втором варианте. Или лучше записать в каком-то ином виде? То есть я понимаю, что можно написать: "...то в отношении всех последующих комментариев обретается вера и понимание." Но как лучше обойтись без этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь идёт о вере **именно в комментарии**, то, конечно, этого не понять из первого варианта. Во втором тоже нельзя оставлять предлог в "подвешенном состоянии" — звучит не по-русски. Я бы переделал так:

*Если понять только то, что написано в Писании, то естественным образом обретается вера во все последующие комментарии и их понимание.*

Comment: Звучит тоже не совсем. Обретается вера в понимание или само понимание? Если второе, тогда лучше использовать повторяющийся союз "и ... и" или союз "а также" вместо "и" .

Comment: Конечно второе. Ну не знаю, формально, конечно, можно прочитать как "вера в понимание", но по здравом размышлении я бы такую интерпретацию в любом случае отсёк.

Comment: Да я бы и "веру во все комментарии" тоже *в любом случае отсёк* :)

Comment: *Продолжение:* А вообще, если двусмысленность всё же может возникнуть, Ваш вариант с "а также" вполне поддерживаю. Но если можно оставить мой, более простой, вариант, то я бы оставил. Ну что, право же, за вера в понимание! :)

Comment: *Да я бы и "веру во все комментарии" тоже в любом случае отсёк :)* Согласен, тоже странновато звучит. ;)

Comment: Наверняка ведь должно быть **обрести веру** (в обычном понимании) и **понять комментарии**.

Comment: Ну да, согласен, конечно.

Comment: Вера обретается не только в Господа Бога, но и в людей, бренды, направления мысли, тенденции и т.д. В том числе и в конкретную книгу, в то, что там изложено.